# The direction of the steepest descent path at the saddle point (Picard-Lefschetz theory)

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, stationary-point, oscillatory-integral

I am having to perform oscillatory integrations like $e^{iS}$ using Picard-Lefschetz theory. One can write this as $e^{h+is}$ where $h(x,y)=-{\rm Im}(S(x,y))$ is the Morse function. To perform these kinds of integrals one deforms the integration contour along Lefschetz thimbles on which $is$ freezes to a constant and and the Morse function has a large negative value towards the end points of the contour. Then the integration can be well approximated by the steepest descent method. Now, I need to figure out the angle this steepest descent contour makes at the saddle point. In [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.100.123543) (open access) it is stated that ***"the direction of the steepest
descent path at the saddle point is given by the direction
$\theta$ of the eigenvector of the Hessian matrix for the Morse
function, associated with the negative eigenvalue"*** (see, page 13, left column, after eq. no. 65).

I want to know how to prove this: ***"the direction of the steepest
descent path at the saddle point is given by the direction
$\theta$ of the eigenvector of the Hessian matrix for the Morse
function, associated with the negative eigenvalue"***

Comment: Is this revelent? https://people.math.osu.edu/tanveer.1/m805/supplement.steepest.pdf